# How to change PHPStorm 8 default new project location?

Tags: directory, location, default, phpstorm

When I create a new project, I must edit the current project location each time, because our global projects are on:

```
~/Sites/
```

However, PHPStorm sets it default as:

```
~/PhpstormProjects/
```

How can I change the default location as mine?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no GUI for that.

PhpStorm should remember last used folder (when you successfully created new project) and use it by default for next one (does for me; although I'm using the same path since v1 .. maybe this was broken since then).

If it does not and if you have brave heart .. you can edit config file directly :)

**PhpStorm v8 and earlier:**

- Close IDE
- Open this file in any text editor: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80\config\options\ide.general.xml` (path is for PhpStorm v8 on Windows 7; for other OS/versions please see this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs )
- File is very short -- just find `<option name="lastProjectLocation"` node and edit `value` attribute -- put desired path there
- Save changes, Launch IDE and see if it worked for you.

**PhpStorm v9 and newer:** such setting is now located in `recentProjectDirectories.xml` file -- look for  `<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="LAST_PATH_HERE" />` entry.

---

There is a ticket asking for a GUI setting for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8839 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

For default folder for "Open Folder" kind of dialogs -- follow [IDEA-84622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84622) ticket.

---

**UPDATE 2018-05-25:**

**2018.2** will have a GUI field for that (`Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings`) -- see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84622#comment=27-2740074).

[image]

Comment: I added this option but it does not seem to work in v8

Comment: @Konstantin I've just tested it again on v8.0.2 final  running on Windows 7 x64 .. and it worked for me. No idea why it may not work for you.

Comment: I have 10 and this option no longer appears to be in there. However, for software that says you can edit everything, it really should have such a commonly wanted option available in the GUI.

Comment: @Brett 1) Such setting is now located in different config file -- see updated answer. 2) *"However, for software that says you can edit everything,"* and you can edit it, right :) ? Not via GUI but you still can edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. :)

Comment: I have the same problem, my config is in `recentProjectDirectories.xml` but when i save my new path then I restart phpstorm, he replace my new path with the first one ! Have you an idea ?

Comment: @Prince No idea. TBH I have installed "FavoriteFolders" plugin and added the desired folder to the folder chooser dialog (I'm on Windows, so IDE uses own dialog; on Mac it will use native one) where with single click I can go to a desired default folder. Obviously, it's mainly for opening the project. When creating projects... well ... I do not create blank projects in IDE. I create folders in advance or via composer.. and then just use "Open" to point to the project root folder .. and there the aforementioned plugin works.

Comment: @Prince But a special option was implemented already (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84622#comment=27-2740074) -- it should be available in 2018.2 (you can try EAP builds if you wish)

Answer (score 2):

Create the folder the you wanna use(Ex: /ProgramasBMO), and then go to:

1) File --> Settings (It will open a window)

2) Click on "System Settings"

3) Write the path to your folder

4) Done :)

[image: Project Opening.png]