# How to change the default new/open project directory in PhpStorm 8?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

When I click open or new project **PhpStorm** shows the way to **C:\User\Myname**. Tell me how to change this to **C:\xamp\www** ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no GUI for that.

PhpStorm should remember last used folder (when you successfully created new project) and use it by default for next one (does for me; although I'm using the same path since v1 .. maybe this was broken since then).

If it does not and if you have brave heart .. you can edit config file directly :)

- Close IDE
- Open this file in any text editor: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80\config\options\ide.general.xml` (path is for PhpStorm v8 on Windows 7; for other OS/versions please see this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs )
- File is very short -- just find `<option name="lastProjectLocation"` node and edit `value` attribute -- put desired path there
- Save changes, Launch IDE and see if it worked for you.

Comment: Lazy indeed. I see you copied your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073690/how-to-change-phpstorm-8-default-new-project-location.

Comment: @user2078023 Well ... you can solve it my using FavoriteFolders plugin -- it can add custom buttons to such dialogs (can be project specific and IDE wide). May not do any good for MacOS as AFAIK it uses native file chooser (Finder) .. but then it can be solved with Finder itself. At very least it does the job for me here on Windows -- one click and I'm in the "MyProjects" root folder.