# How do i change the default folder in WebStorm?

Tags: web, configuration, config, webstorm

When I open WebStorm and click the "Open" icon, WebStorm suggests to open files from the `C:\users\USERNAME` directory:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRKk.png)

How do I change this default directory to a different one?

I have read the following post which helps to set the default directory when creating a new project:
[How to change PHPStorm 8 default new project location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073690/how-to-change-phpstorm-8-default-new-project-location)

But it does not explain how to set the default directory when **opening** a project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

To change the default folder go to **File - Settings** or (Ctrl-Alt-S).

Then change **default directory** to your **path**.

Then **apply** and **save**.

*I uploaded the print-screen to visualize this process.*

[image: type your directory]

Answer (score 2):

When using File/Open, WebStorm normally opens the last chosen directory. But, when opening a folder for a very first time, it opens your %HOME% directory. You can try passing different %HOME% to WebStorm using `"-Duser.home=<path to your new home>"` , but this will change WebStorm default configuration storage location and affect other functionality that relies on user home value

Comment: Where should I type this command? What other functionality will it affect? is it considered dangerous to change this configuration? Thanks!

Comment: to pass this option, you need to modify bin/WebStorm.exe.vmoptions file. This change will mostly affect default configuration storage location