# Changing the default project directory in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Whenever I start a new project in `PhpStorm` it always defaults to the directory:

```
C:\Users\Brett\PhpstormProjects\untitled
```

This is rather annoying as my directory I put sites in is in a whole other drive and I have to keep navigating to this other directory.

Is there any way this can be changed?

Comment: Either manually as I have suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26074046/783119 or you may install `FavoriteFolders` plugin and add such default location as a button -- so when you need to specify a folder, you click on `...` to bring "Choose Folder" dialog and that button will be there.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. :)